# Почему отображается только последняя картинка при отображении списка?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Хочу сделать кнопки с иконками.

Во вьюмодели:

```
public string Icon
{
  get { return icon; }
  set
  {
    icon = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

Ну и какое нибудь значение:

```
this.Icon = "pack://application:,,,/Icons/folder_96px.png";
```

В разметке:

```
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="IconButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButton}">
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

А в итоге выглядит странно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Погуглил, дело вроде решается каким то флагом x:Shared="False", но при такой разметке не понимаю куда втыкать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы делаете почти правильно.

Дело в том, что расшаривать UI-элементы нельзя: ведь у UI-элемента может быть только один предок. Решение с `x:Shared` — грубый хак. Правильно будет расшаривать не UI-элементы, а темплейты.

Итого получаем:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="IconButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButton}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Icon}"/>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Вот же блин, даже не задумался, что можно переопределить темплейт и работать уже как с любым другим контентом.