# Как биндить адрес иконки в иконку MenuItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В продолжение [прошлого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/534128). Накидал простой стиль, чтобы свой класс команд легко биндить в меню:

```
    <Style x:Key="ContentMenuItem" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SubItems}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding FontWeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
    </Style>
```

Тут я не вижу способа разделить `Icon` от `MenuItem` на свойство с адресом и его представление, а если забивать в `Image`, то опять получаю последнюю иконку из коллекции.

Я так понимаю, из рабочих вариантов остаются - конвертер, который возвращает экземпляры `Image` и переписывание темплейта `MenuItem`, что делать не хочется, смысла в этом мало.

Может я опять упустил простой и очевидный способ решить эту проблему?

Как вообще работают с менюшками \ коллекциями действий над отображаемым элементом?

Comment: Простой способ - биндиться к коллекции объектов, которые описывают каждый пункт меню: хидер, тултип, команду, иконку....

Comment: @vitidev стиль в шапке это и делает. Единственное что, иконка у меня не типа Image, а строка адреса с изображением в ресурсах.

Comment: Просто  ваши "смысла в этом мало" и есть очевидные пути решения проблемы. Конвертер нужен если MVVM чтобы было чистенько, а переопределение шаблона - самое первое решение подобных задач, а стилями уже решается то, что нельзя решить в лоб шаблонами.

Comment: @Monk: А чего именно вы хотите добиться? Расскажите на словах.

Comment: @vitidev если для любого действия нужно переписывать шаблон, то фреймворк - говно. Вот я и ищу варианты.

Comment: @VladD у контекстного меню иконки можно делать, особенно полезно, когда в меню есть и иконка и текст, а где то только иконка потом используется. Собсна, не понял, можно ли как то тут забиндить адрес к иконке, учитывая что темлейт для отображения иконки явно перебить нельзя.

Comment: @Monk: Ничего не понятно. У вас есть VM-класс для MenuItem'а, правильно? И как он выглядит?

Comment: @VladD, https://github.com/MonkAlex/MangaReader/blob/master/MangaReader/ViewModel/Commands/Primitives/ContentMenuItem.cs - вот он. Обычный класс с INPC. Единственное что, Icon - строка, а не изображение. И после бинда опять получается шаредное изображение, проблема то с прошлого вопроса.

Comment: @Monk: Хм, я в вашем стиле вообще не вижу работы с иконкой. Почему не `<Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Icon}"/>`?

Comment: @VladD, так та же самая проблема вылазит - в менюшке только у последнего элемента иконка.

Comment: @Monk: Странно, не должно быть. Сейчас перепроверю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший вопрос.

Смотрите в чём проблема. `MenuItem.Icon` — не `Uri`, который определяет иконку. Это объект, который будет отображаться — аналогично свойству `Content` и `Button`'а.

Проблема в том, что `Button` предоставляет `ContentTemplate`, чтобы можно быть `Content` забиндить из VM, а способ его отображения указать в темплейте. А вот для `MenuItem`'а добавить `IconTemplate` забыли.

---

Окей, как же тогда решать проблему? Есть несколько путей, самым чистым мне кажется вот какой.

Проблема в том, что `Icon` не знает, как отображать нашу строку. (Присваивать `Image` в стиле нельзя, разумеется.) Поэтому положим-ка мы туда другой тип, который будет известно, как отображать.

Заведём специальный VM-тип `ImageSourceVM`, очень простой:

```
class ImageSourceVM
{
    public ImageSourceVM(string source) { Source = source; }
    public string Source { get; }
}
```

Нам даже не нужно `NotifyPropertyChanged` здесь, так как мы никогда не будем изменять `Source`: при случае нужно будет просто подменить один `ImageSourceVM` на другой.

Теперь, его отображение. Оно будет везде одинаковое, поэтому положим его в шаблон куда-нибудь в `App.xaml`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ImageSourceVM}">
    <Image Source="{Binding Source}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Теперь в нашей VM меняем тип `Icon` с `string` на `ImageSourceVM`, прописываем в стиле

```
<Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Icon}"/>
```

— и всё работает.

---

Кстати, это же решение можно использовать и для `Button`'а, чтобы не менять в нём `ContentTemplate`.

Comment: А просто указать в Setter.Value> сразу же  <Image Source="{Binding Source}"/> нельзя? без заведения всяких вьюмоделей, чтобы просто прицепиться  к их типу?

Comment: @vitidev: Нет, в стиле вы не сможете задать визуальный элемент, потому что этот один элемент будет расшарен между всеми точками применения стиля. Для расшаривания визуальных элементов как раз и нужны темплейты.

Comment: @vitidev нет, в этом и соль. Сам объект Image получается один на всех. А они так не работают.

Comment: @VladD проверил - завелось. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Monk: Пожалуйста!