# Binding к Icon в ItemContainerStyle Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Есть XAML :

```
  <Menu Width="Auto">
    <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding Path=листОбъектов, Source={x:Static тут:статичекий.синглтон.класса}}">
      <MenuItem.Header>
        <Image Source="Какой_нибудь_путь_к_картинке" Width="16" Height="16"/>
      </MenuItem.Header>
      <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
          <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=TypeObjectName}"/>
          <Setter Property="Icon">
            <Setter.Value>
              <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding Path=IconSource}" />
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
```

`IconSource` везде заполнены, однако в `MenuItem` отображаются иконки только у последнего элемента.

Comment: Проблема в том, что один и тот же UI-элемент (например, `Image`) нельзя повторно использовать. А ваш `Image` из стиля (он там в одном экземпляре) используется для всех item'ов! Насколько я понимаю, ваш вопрос уже рассматривался тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/534269/10105

Comment: (То есть там объяснение не для вашего случая, а код подойдёт и вам.)

Comment: @VladD Ну я использую аналогичный метод и для TreeView, однако проблем не возникало. Сейчас попробую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал через ItemTemplate, спасибо @VladD за пояснения

```
<MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid>
          <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding Path=IconSource}" />
          <Image Source="Маханькая_иконошка" Width="8" Height="8" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </Grid>
      </Border>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=TypeObjectName}"/>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
```